# ¿Cómo puedo aplicar una transición a dos elementos a la vez?

Tags: html, css, css-transform

Quiero aplicar una transición a la imagen de fondo cuando el cursor pasa sobre el botón azul. Actualmente solo se aplica cuando pasa sobre la imagen misma. El botón tiene su propia transición que se debe aplicar solo a él, mientras que se debe aplicar la suya a la imagen de fondo.

[Transición sobre imagen de fondo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec9oj.jpg)

[Transición sobre botón](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0pJI.png)

[Funcionamiento esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioIu6.png)

HTML:

```
<section class="cover">
          <div class="cover__overlay">
            <h2 class="cover__title">Visítanos</h2>
            <p class="cover__subtitle">
              Todo el año <br />
              Galería de Arte de Practicum <br />
              404, Avenida Tim Berners-Lee.
            </p>
            <div class="cover__frame">
              <p class="cover_paragraph">Comprar entradas</p>
            </div>
            <img
              src="./images/grid-image5.png"
              alt="Fotografía de un campo"
              class="cover__background"
            />
          </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
.cover__overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 93%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cover__title {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cover__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cover__frame {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #0278fe;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cover__frame:hover {
  background: #0063d2;
}

.cover_paragraph {
  margin: 0;
}

.cover__background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #2a2c2f;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.cover__background:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: #2a2c2f;
}
```

Intenté hacer la siguiente combinación pero no realiza ninguna modificación:

```
.cover__background:hover + .cover__frame {
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: #2a2c2f;
}
```

La imagen de fondo tiene un posicionamiento absoluto pues necesito poder aplicarle la transición y al ponerla como background image, no logré hacerle modificaciones ni que mantuviera el formato adaptativo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
.cover__frame:hover {
  background: #0063d2;
}

.cover__frame:hover + .cover__background {
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: #2a2c2f;
}
```